# Execution Failed for task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac in Android Studio java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-room

I am developing an Android App in Android Studio with MacBook m1 pro. Not quite sure what went wrong, I think it's related to room.

Here is the error:

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I have 2 classes in my app.

my classes:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    public static final String COLLECTION_NAME = "users";

    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    String name = "";
    String phone = "";
    String email = "";
    String password = "";
    String location = "";
    String gender = "";
    String age = "";
    Long updateDate = new Long(0);

    @Ignore
    public User(){} //for room

    //TODO: add location
    public User(String name, String phone, String email, String password, String gender, String age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.location = location;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.age = age;
    }

public class Post {
    final public static String COLLECTION_NAME = "posts";

    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    String id = "";
    String name ="";
    String userId = "";
    Long postTime = new Long(0);
    String text = "";
    String image = "";
    String type = "";
    String age = "";
    String size = "";
    String gender = "";
    String location = "";

    @Ignore
    public Post(){}

    public Post(String id, String userId, String text, String image, String type, String age, String size, String gender, String location){  //}), List<String> likesUserId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.text = text;
        this.image = image;
        this.type = type;
        this.age = age;
        this.size = size;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.location = location;
    }
```

my app gradel:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.findmehomeapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-common:2.2.6'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.6'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.6'
    def nav_version = "2.3.5"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.3')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'

}
```

project gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
        def nav_version = "2.3.5"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I had tried:

1. Invalidate Caches and restart.
2. Build -> clean project.
3. Remove and add stuff to my grade.
4. Change @Ignore place in the classes and remove.

I really hope someone will be able to help.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

Update Room version to 2.4.0-alpha03 or above

**Long Answer:**

I was having the same issue and tried all these methods but none of them worked. Then I performed following steps:

1. Click on "Run with --stacktrace option" in the build tab under the exception. It will show you the root cause of the issue.
2. Then you can further look into the error and its resolution.

For me the error was the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: No native library is found for os.name=Mac and os.arch=aarch64. path=/org/sqlite/native/Mac/aarch64
```

After looking into it further, I found that it was the exception from the Room library, I was using the older version which does not support Mac M1 chip. So I have changed its version to 2.4.0-alpha03 or above

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue and I changed 2 things and solved problem.

1. File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location and click "JDK location was moved to Gradle Settings." Then, select **"Android studio default jdk version (version 11)"** and apply. First step is done.
2. File -> Project Structure -> Modules, make sure **Source Compability** and **Target Compability** is **"$JavaVersion.VERSION__11"** and apply.

I use **Kotlin** version is **1.6.10**, it may also important.

Comment: Same here, can you tell us the buildToolsVersion ?

Comment: compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

Comment: Why is `Android studio default jdk version (version 11)` necessary?

Answer (score 0):

you can change **implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'** to **implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'**

Comment: it didn't help but thank you